# FMDB compatibility to Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite, xcode4.2

I've used FMDB in the past when working with a database application on the iPhone.  After the upgrade to Xcode 4.2 I can no longer access the FMDB (errors are given).

Is there an easy way to access databases that are similar to using the FBDB library?

Here is the error image after I removed all the release And autorelease?

[image]

Error:

**duplicate symbol _main in /Users/omaktechnologies/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VDineOrdering-akmhhdfmiobkmshbfvwzffnedyaf/Build/Intermediates/VDineOrdering.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VDineOrdering.build/Objects-normal/i386/fmdb.o and /Users/omaktechnologies/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VDineOrdering-akmhhdfmiobkmshbfvwzffnedyaf/Build/Intermediates/VDineOrdering.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VDineOrdering.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o for architecture i386
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with** exit code 1

Comment: What exactly are the errors you're receiving?

Comment: 4.2 doesn't necessarily mean ARC. You're saying you modified the FMDB project to remove all release/autorelease messages? I can't quite make out your error screenshot... you should probably copy/paste the text of the error.

Comment: @livingtech

I added the error below.

Answer (score 1):

FMDB works fine in XCode 4.2, there must be a project configuration issue.

The only other viable path to take is Core Data.

EDIT:  After seeing the errors you have, remove fmdb.m from your target.  The only classes/categories that you should be compiling for FMDB are:

FMDatabase
FMDatabaseAdditions
FMResultSet

Those are all I have.

Comment: Its very big help? how can I do it?

Comment: Do what?  There are many books on moving to Core Data.  As for running FMDB in XCode 4.2, you have to resolve your error - you have not responded to Ryan about posting what errors you are seeing.  All I can say is that I have used FMDB with a project in XCode 4.2 and it works, the same project I used in previous versions of XCpde... there is nothing in FMDB that should break in XCode 4.2, it has to be something wrong in your project.

Comment: I added error after I removed all the release and auto lease and dealloc ?

you can see it right?

why is the reason for that ?